# Exec alternative

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec

***The problem***

I've written a function that receives a function name as a string and places it in a priority queue for execution. This works if I use exec, but I don't want to leave it like this because of the inherent security issues.

All of the other alternatives I've found require the received function name to be without the brackets at the end. I need to keep them in place, until I'm able to rewrite the 'sending' code.

***The question***

Is there an alternative to exec that will work with the functions brackets in place?

***Sample code:***

Listening / queuing function:

```
def queue_listener():
    listener = multiprocessing.connection.Listener(('localhost', 6000), authkey=b'secret password')
    global task_queue
    task_queue = PriorityQueue()
    try:
        while True:
            conn = listener.accept()
            msg = None
            try:
                msg = conn.recv()
                print("Recv: " + msg)
                task_queue.put(ast.literal_eval(msg))
            except EOFError:
                listener.close() #Ignore end of file errors.
    except Exception as err:
        '''Do some logging '''
        return 1
    finally:
        listener.close()
        return 0
```

Processing function:

```
def task_queue_processor():
    global task_queue
    try:
        while True:
            task_queue_item = task_queue.get()
            print("Proc: " + str(task_queue_item))
            exec(task_queue_item[1])
    except Exception as err:
        '''Do some logging'''
        return 1
    finally:
        task_queue_item = None
        return 0
```

Here's an example of the function name as received by the listener:

> "read_device()"
> or possibly
> "read_device([3],[8])"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why does it receive the name of a function as a string instead of the function itself?

Comment: It's send as a string by the multiprocessing sending process.